# How to get robot position in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want get the robot position(something like the coordinate x,y,z) , I know that  hector_gazebo_plugins can do this,but I don't know how to use the API,did something more simple to get the robot position in gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244659/how-to-get-robot-position-in-gazebo?/) by [chenlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/27694/chenlee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [answer here](http://answers.ros.org/question/246440/husky-perfect-localization-gazebo-positioning-system/?comment=247207#post-id-247207) applies to your use case, if you are interested in getting the robot pose as a ROS message.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0